# For a finite (or countable) ring $R$, the matrices representing the group laws for $\cdot, +$ in $R$ have determinant $0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, modular-arithmetic, determinant

For example, the group law for $\Bbb{Z}/4$ is $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 \\ 2 & 3 & 0 & 1 \\ 3 & 0 & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$.  Because $\det(\sigma(A)) = (\pm 1)\det (A)$ for any column or row permutation, it does not matter how you index the rows or columns with elements of $\Bbb{Z}/4$.  That also means the theorem says that more than just the explicit matrices have zero determinant, but any row or column permutation of those matrices will as well.

Title is a conjecture.

So that example is of the group law $(\Bbb{Z}/4, +)$ but it also works when you consider the monoid law (this is obvious since there's always a column of $0$'s representing $0\cdot x = 0, \forall x \in R$ the ring.)

And coincidentally, it also works for the unit group law.  That is, modulo $4$ we have: $\det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = 1^2 - 3^2 = -8 = 0 \pmod 4$.

Why would this be true?  Is there some generalization / concept I'm unaware of that explains this and other determinant phenomena?

Comment: Is the ring commutative?

Comment: @Yorch yes, please assume for simplicity that it's commutative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we are working with a commutative ring.

For the addition one work with the matrix $A´$ where you substract the first row (corresponding to $0$) to the second row (corresponding to $1$). This new second row can be used on any other row (corresponding to $a$) to make it into the first row ( by substracting $a$ times the second row). This will make it have two equal rows, it follows the determinant is $0$ for any ring with at least $3$ elements.

For the multiplication one take another row (corresponding to $a$) and substract $a$ times the first row (corresponding to $1$) and you get a row of all zeros, so the determinant is zero. If the ring has only one unit then the determinant is $1$.